# Display person-card directly without hover

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm building SPFx solution which pull users from SharePoint list. I want to show user details and along with Email, Phone number, Call Icons similar to person card.

Since Microsoft graph toolkit already has an component names person-card, I would like to use by passing email parameter of the user to component. But when I saw the document and jsfiddler example. Both are showing the display person card based on hover. But I want to show it directly instead of hover or click.

Please point me to right direction if I miss anything from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/toolkit/components/person).

```
<mgt-person person-query="me" show-name show-email person-card="hover">
    </mgt-person>
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to programmatically show the person-card from the person component, then I agree with Shane. However, if you don't care about the person component, then you can use the `mgt-person-card` component directly and use the `personDetails` and `personImage` properties to set the details to show.

Comment: you can also create alike card using `persona` control provided by `office UI Fabric`

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible with the Microsoft Graph Toolkit (v1.1.1) to programatically show/hide the card in `mgt-person` component.

However, I agree that this is important functionality to have. Please submit this feature request as an issue on our GitHub so we can discuss specifics and get it scheduled for the next release.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues

Comment: Thanks for your input. I raised a ticket in github issues.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/321